# In the given figure, $X$ and $Y$ are two centres

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $X$ and $Y$ are two centres of two circles. They touch each other externally at a point $S$. $AB$ be the common tangent of both circles. $O$ be the centre of the third circle which touches the two circles at points $Q$ and $R$. If $AX=h$, $OM=f$ and $BY=g$, then prove that $$\frac {1}{\sqrt { f }}=\frac {1}{\sqrt { h }} +\frac {1}{\sqrt { g }}$$

[image]

My attempt

If we join $OA$ we have, 
$$f^2={OA}^2-{AM}^2=$$; using pythagoras theorem

Again if we join $OB$ then 
$$f^2={OB}^2-{MB}^2$$ 
Now how should I move further?

Comment: Maybe [Decartes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem) applies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the radius of a third tangent circle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071577/finding-the-radius-of-a-third-tangent-circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long is AB?

$XY = g + h$
you have a already constructed parallel to $AB$ from $Y$ to an unidentified point that I will call $Y'$

$YY' = h-g\\
(h-g)^2 + AB^2 = (h+g)^2\\
AB^2 = 4gh$

We can do a similar construction to get $BM$ and $AM$

$BM^2 = 4fg\\
AM^2 = 4fh\\
\sqrt {4fg} + \sqrt{4fh} = \sqrt{4gh}$

divide trough by $2\sqrt{fgh}$ and we get our desired result.

Comment: I couldn't understand your parallel concept, please clarify.

Comment: You have constructed a line in your diagram that is parallel to AB and intersects Y, forming a narrow little right triangle.  One leg is has the same length as AB, one leg has a length equal to h-g, and the hypotenuse = XY has a length equal to g+h

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$BM^2=(g+f)^2-(g-f)^2=4gf$
$AM^2=(h+f)^2-(h-f)^2=4hf$
$(AM+BM)^2=(g+h)^2-(g-h)^2=4gh$

Square root both sides of all three expressions, then plug the first two expressions into the third one,  and you get the final equality you need to prove.

Comment: How do you get the first step?